# Awsec2 alarm related issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, alarms

hi I am new with Aws alarm & all other stuff, Actually one of the past employee of our company has worked on aws all alarm set & all stuff now he left so I have to handle this issue ,I need little bit help like we have been getting such messages infrequently

> You are receiving this email because your Amazon CloudWatch Alarm
>   "Network In - awsec2-XYZ-Instance-i-XXXXXXX-High-Network-In" in the US
>   - N. Virginia region has entered the ALARM state, because "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (1.021700525E7) was greater than or equal to the
>   threshold (1.0E7)." at "Tuesday 06 May, 2014 04:49:17 UTC".

Our website don't have such traffic but we are getting alarm notify can anyone help me some common issues what may be issue to trigger where we don't have very much traffic on website.
Is there some common issue possible please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please go AWS console then Cloudwatch service then find that alarm which is Network In Please check threshold and increase it to that point which you think would be critical. Like Increase to 5.0 . let me know how it goes